# How to set columnrange width to expand the length of the x-axis in multiple data series in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to make a chart with that has 3 data series; a box plot, bubble, and column range. The box plot has a count of 5. The bubble is only displayed on one point of the box plot. The column range's data count is 1 and should span the whole x-axis. Basically, the chart should look somewhat like this:

[image]

This is the data I used:

```
var columnRangeData = [[750, 1050]],
    boxPlotData = [
        [625, 625, 725, 825, 825],
        [650, 650, 762.5, 875, 875],
        [800, 800, 875, 950, 950],
        [925, 925, 975, 1025, 1025],
        [1025, 1025, 1087.5, 1150, 1150]
    ],
    bubbleData = [
        [1, 640, 2],
        [1, 800, 10],
        [1, 890, 3],
        [1, 930, 4],
        [1, 975, 2],
        [1, 1050, 2]
    ];
```

So far, this is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/Dhm2N/1/ I can't seem to figure out how to make the column range expand to the width of the x-axis. Help on how to achieve it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` to extend columnrange to fit full category width. see: http://jsfiddle.net/Dhm2N/2/